# Uploading app on Samsung Galaxy Store Error

Tags: java, android, google-play, galaxy

I was uploading an app I already have available on Google Play and Amazon AppStore onto Samsung Apps. The app is developed in the latest version of Android Studio. When I upload the apk, it shows an error that says:

> Signature is invalid. (No JAR signatures)

I am not sure how to fix this so could I please get some help

I'm uploading the signed APP just like in Google Play and Amazon AppStore.

Comment: Maybe samsung galaxy store does not support JAR signature that you use. Did you try to sign apk with only v1 or v2 signature ?

Comment: Build:
V1 (Jar Signature): Signature is invalid. (No JAR signatures)

Build: 
V2 (Full APK Signature): Signature is invalid. (No JAR signatures)

Build:
V1 & V2: Signature is invalid. (No JAR signatures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was Android Studio. Upgrade to the Version:

Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 15, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Build: V1 & V2 and it worked.